# Reload parent page when modal box closes

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am using the jquery simplemodal plugin to popup a modal box and display a form I want to bind an event to the window close that reloads the parent page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or

```
onClose: function() {
    window.location.reload(true);
}
```

**See Also:**

[SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#options), you should be able to bind an event to the `onClose` to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
   $(".someSelector").modal(
     {
       onClose: function (dialog) {
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
       }
   });
```